# forward declaration not working

Tags: c++, namespaces, forward-declaration

My forward declaration doesnt work if i do it like this:

```
class Manager::TagManager;

namespace UI
{

    class Example
    {
    public:
    ...

    Manager::TagManager* tagManager_;


    };
}
```

it says use of undefined type. However it works fine like so:

```
namespace Manager
{
     class TagManager;
}

//same stuff follows
```

So whats the difference?
is "class Manager::TagManager;" not a declaration of TagManager in namespace Manager?

Comment: Just for the record, if `Manager` is a namespace: `namespace Manager {class TagManager;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rhetorical question: how would you expect the compiler to know whether `class Manager::TagManager` is a declaration of class `TagManager` in namespace `Manager` or a declaration of nested class `TagManager` in enclosing class `Manager`? The compiler never heard about `Manager` before. It has no idea whether it is a class or a namespace. This is what the compiler is trying to tell you by that error message. It actually assumes that `Manager` is a class type (not a namespace), which has not been defined.

However, even if it knew what `Manager` was, it still wouldn't work. In C++ qualified names like `Name1::Name2` can only be used to refer to *existing* (i.e. already declared) entities. You cannot use qualified names to declare *new* entities.

That means that a forward declaration of an entity that belongs to a namespace can only be done by reopening that namespace. A forward declaration of an entity that is nested into a class can only be done inside the definition of the enclosing class.

With entities in namespaces it is relatively easy, since you can reopen namespaces as many times as you want. With nested entities in classes you get only one chance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is, in my opinion, a design flaw with the language.  It should work the same either way, except it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

No, you never told the compiler that `Manager` is a namespace. It could be `class Manager`. (That is probably why it says "undefined type," the error message is not considering the possibility that it is a namespace.)

You can't add a member to anything outside the scope of its own definition. It would break separation of concerns if you could declare something in a namespace without a namespace declaration.

If you must have the name `Manager::TagManager` work without a declaration of that specific class in `Manager`, you can use a `using namespace` declaration inside `Manager` and declare the class in another namespace. There are occasionally other ways around the rule that things must be declared in their enclosing entity, but they are just name lookup hacks and do not alter what owns or contains what.