# Forward declaration is not working as expected

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, ros

I'm defining a class `SpatialCriterionCallback` in a header file "spatialcriterion.h" like this:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "neuromorphic_stereo/MatchingCandidates.h"
#include <vector>

class SpatialCriterionCallback
{
public:
  // constructors & destructors
  SpatialCriterionCallback()=default;
  SpatialCriterionCallback(ros::NodeHandle);
  ~SpatialCriterionCallback()=default;
private:
  std::vector<neuromorphic_stereo::MatchingCandidates> matching_candidates;
  void subscriberCallbackFunction(constneuromorphic_stereo::MatchingCandidates&);
}
```

Then in the file "spatialcriterion.cpp" I'm defining a constructor that invokes a ros::SubscriberNode like this:

```
#include "spatialcriterioncallback.h"

SpatialCriterionCallback::SpatialCriterionCallback(ros::NodeHandle n)
{
  this->n =n;
  this->time_criterion_topic_handle = this->n.subscribe("TimeCriterionTopic",
                                                        1e4,
                                                        &SpatialCriterionCallback::subscriberCallbackFunction,
                                                        this);



}
```

When I try compiling this within a qtcreator project, the compiler tells me

> error: undefined reference to
>   `SpatialCriterionCallback::subscriberCallbackFunction(neuromorphic_stereo::MatchingCandidates_ const&)'

When I add the following lines to my "spatialcriterion.cpp" file it will compile just fine:

```
void SpatialCriterionCallback::subscriberCallbackFunction(const neuromorphic_stereo::MatchingCandidates & msg){
  this->matching_candidates.push_back(msg);
}
```

Now my question is: Shouldn't this code compile without the function definition, because the function `subscriberCallbackFunction()` has already been declared in "spatialcriterion.h"? Why is it necessary for the compiler to have the function defined?
I also tried finding an explanation to this behaviour here, but all the other posts about failing forward declaration (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459416/forward-declaration-not-working) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009716/forward-declaration-not-working-does-not-have-a-type-error)) aren't exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's a linker error. The term "forward declaration" is usually not applied to member function declarations (only to types) so you're unlikely to find answers by searching for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you declared the method in your class, it doesn't exist.

When you reference that function in the constructor, the **linker** tells you that it needs to know where the method is.

The code compiles fine, it doesn't **link**.